# Idiom-request: What do you call a book/movie with a poor story line and excessive pathos?

Tags: idiom-requests

I'm not a native English speaker, but I think there was definitely an idiom that describes **a book, a movie or a screenplay that has a poor story line, shallow characters, too much heroic pathos** etc.

I think it was something like "cranberry sauce"... Or "cranberry jam" maybe. Definitely something with berries (I think).

"Golden Raspberry Awards" mentioned in the comments does ring a bell, thanks. But is there an established idiom to describe it? Something close to "pops", "bubblegum culture", "kitsch"... We do call it "cranberry" where I live in the EU, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Are you thinking of the "[Raspberry Awards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Raspberry_Awards)"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA oh... May be. Thanks for the link! But is there an established idiom to describe it? Something close to "pops", "bubblegum culture", "kitsch"... We do call it "cranberry" where I live in the EU, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: You can edit your question and include the information you told me if you want. The more detail and "research" the better. It might also help if you provided the word in your native language, this is a multinational site, so users may know how best to translate the expression.

Comment: _Schmaltz_, which is the fat derived from poultry, is used to describe films or books of excessive sentimentally. It doesn't completely fit your definition, but it does have the food connection. And the word _cranberry_ comes from crane berry, so there is also a bird connection!

Answer (score 2):

This is a pot boiler, potboiler, or pot-boiler.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pot_boiler):

> Noun **pot boiler** (plural pot boilers)
>
> (mildly derogatory) A creative work of low quality (book, art, etc),
>   produced merely to earn a living or for profit, as opposed to serious
>   creative expression.

And from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potboiler):

> A potboiler or pot-boiler is a novel, play, opera, film, or other
>   creative work of dubious literary or artistic merit, whose main
>   purpose was to pay for the creator's daily expenses—thus the imagery
>   of "boil the pot", which means "to provide one's livelihood". Authors
>   who create potboiler novels or screenplays are sometimes called *hack*
>   *writers* or *hacks*. Novels deemed to be potboilers may also be called
>   *pulp fiction*, and potboiler films may be called *popcorn movies*.

[tidied]

Answer (score 2):

This can be called ***fluff***

Defined by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fluff) as:

> Entertainment or writing perceived as trivial or superficial.
>   *‘the film is a piece of typical Hollywood fluff’*

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [narm](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Narm)? From TVTropes:

> **Narm** is a moment that is supposed to be serious, but due to either over-sappiness, poor execution, excessive melodrama, or the sheer absurdity of the situation, the drama is lost to the point of surpassing "cheesy" and becoming unintentionally funny.

---

Glurge is somewhat similar, except more specific to over-the-top sentimentality/inspiration. From [TVTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Glurge):

> **Glurge** is a catch-all term for any "inspirational" tale which conceals a much darker meaning than the uplifting moral lessons it purports to offer. The word "glurge" was initially coined by a reader of Snopes.com and derives from the sound of someone throwing up.

Its origins are from [snopes](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/category/glurge-gallery/):

> In ordinary language, **glurge** is the sending of inspirational (and supposedly “true”) tales, ones that often conceal much darker meanings than the uplifting moral lessons they purport to offer or undermine their messages by fabricating and distorting historical fact in the guise of offering a “true story.”

Comment: 'Glurge' seems extremely rare, and 'narm' rare, according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=narm%2Cglurge%2Cpot+boiler%2Cpotboiler%2Cpot-boiler&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnarm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpot%20boiler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpotboiler%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpot%20-%20boiler%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Although "narm" is more comparable with "pot boiler" and variants on [Google Trends](https://trends.google.co.uk/trends/explore?geo=GB&q=narm,pot%20boiler).

Comment: Thank you: a new (to me) tool to explore. I'll probably wait until a dictionary or two judge a candidate has passed the 'wordness test', though.

Answer (score 0):

[Mushy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mushy) may fit:

informal, disapproving

> Excessively sentimental.
>
> - ‘a mushy film’

ODO

Also [Hotchpotch](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/it/amp/inglese/hotchpotch) is used to refer to the kind of movies or books you are referring to:

> This is a truly dreadful movie, a hotchpotch of historical inaccuracies and romantic fiction.

Comment: *hotchpotch/hodgepodge* just means a disorganized or incoherent mixture, which is not exactly what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

**Melodrama** is a good possibility, suggesting weak plot and characters and a dependence on emotion. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melodrama